# Android studio 3.1.4 compilation error: "E/vold: Failed to chmod /data/system_ce/0: No such file or directory"

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.0

I am trying to compile the android app and getting this error, tried cleaning, rebuilding, deleting and creating new AVD but nothing working, help would be appreciated

```
08-30 12:52:20.508 1507-1518/? E/vold: Failed to chmod /data/system_ce/0: No such file or directory
    Failed to chmod /data/misc_ce/0: No such file or directory
    Failed to chmod /data/media/0: No such file or directory
08-30 12:52:32.317 1810-1828/? E/BatteryExternalStatsWorker: no controller energy info supplied for telephony
08-30 12:52:32.323 1810-1828/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state (No such file or directory)
08-30 12:52:32.412 1810-1832/? E/LocalDisplayAdapter: Default and active color mode is no longer available! Reverting to first available mode.
08-30 12:52:33.696 1675-1780/? E/storaged: getDiskStats failed with result NOT_SUPPORTED and size 0
08-30 12:52:34.031 1810-1822/? E/SystemServer: Unable to preload default resources
08-30 12:52:36.132 1507-1516/? E/vold: Failed to read field SystemLocale: Success
08-30 12:52:36.134 1810-1888/? E/StorageManagerService: Failed to read field SystemLocale
    android.os.ServiceSpecificException: Failed to read field SystemLocale (code 0)
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1956)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1910)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1860)
        at android.os.IVold$Stub$Proxy.fdeGetField(IVold.java:1094)
        at com.android.server.StorageManagerService.getField(StorageManagerService.java:2408)
        at com.android.server.StorageManagerService.copyLocaleFromMountService(StorageManagerService.java:982)
        at com.android.server.StorageManagerService.handleDaemonConnected(StorageManagerService.java:975)
        at com.android.server.StorageManagerService.access$900(StorageManagerService.java:171)
        at com.android.server.StorageManagerService$StorageManagerServiceHandler.handleMessage(StorageManagerService.java:572)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:65)
08-30 12:52:36.960 1810-1810/? E/UsbDeviceManager: failed to write to /sys/class/android_usb/android0/f_rndis/ethaddr
08-30 12:52:36.969 1810-1810/? E/UsbDeviceManager: Failed to open control for mtp
    Failed to open control for mtp
08-30 12:52:36.988 1810-1810/? E/UsbDeviceManager: Error initializing UsbHandler
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /sys/class/android_usb/android0/state (No such file or directory)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:231)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:165)
        at android.os.FileUtils.readTextFile(FileUtils.java:514)
        at com.android.server.usb.UsbDeviceManager$UsbHandlerLegacy.<init>(UsbDeviceManager.java:1375)
        at com.android.server.usb.UsbDeviceManager.<init>(UsbDeviceManager.java:297)
        at com.android.server.usb.UsbService.<init>(UsbService.java:139)
        at com.android.server.usb.UsbService$Lifecycle.onStart(UsbService.java:73)
        at com.android.server.SystemServiceManager.startService(SystemServiceManager.java:126)
        at com.android.server.SystemServiceManager.startService(SystemServiceManager.java:113)
        at com.android.server.SystemServiceManager.startService(SystemServiceManager.java:72)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.startOtherServices(SystemServer.java:1299)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.run(SystemServer.java:431)
        at com.android.server.SystemServer.main(SystemServer.java:294)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:838)
08-30 12:52:36.996 1810-1810/? E/UsbPortManager: connectToProxy: usb hal service not found. Did the service fail to start?
```

Comment: probably your app need root access by seeing `chmod /data/misc_ce/`,